# Centering Horizontal Scrollview in Android

Tags: android

I have an activity with a Horizontal Scrollview that contains only an ImageView in it. When the activity is started a image is loaded to the ImageView and I want my HorizontalScrollView to appear at the center of the loaded image when the activity starts.

I want it to appear at the center but it keeps appearing at the leftmost end of the picture.
I googled and found several suggestions but none of them work in my case. I have also included the two methods i have already tried in my code snippet.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

    // setting image
    previewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previewImage);
    Container item = Manager.picList.get(Manager.currentPreview);
    previewImage.setImageResource(item.imageId);

    // setting scrollview to center
    previewScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.previewScroll);
    final int centerWidth = previewScroll.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    // METHOD 1
    previewScroll.scrollTo(centerWidth/2,0);

    // METHOD 2
    previewScroll.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            previewScroll.scrollTo(centerWidth/2,0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You could get the view's View Tree Observer using `View.getViewTreeObserver()` and then add a global layout listener that waits for when the view is ready and then adjusts the scroll view accordingly. So you would have something like `previewScroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){ ... }`

Comment: Did this. Didn't help. Did i do it wrong? 
`previewScroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                previewScroll.scrollTo(centerWidth/2,0);
            }
        });`

Comment: Try putting your measuring calculation (including getting centerWidth itself) into the global layout section. Right now you are trying to measure your width using `previewScroll.getChildAt(0).getWidth();` but the child might not be instantiated/drawn yet so the width is going to (potentially) = 0.

Comment: That solved it!
Thanks a lot!!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
private void scrollToCenter(final HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView)
{
    horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()/2,0);
        }
    });
}
```